# Download from a URL with C++

Tags: c++, qt, flickr

I'm playing around with C++ for the first time in years.  Making an app using Qt, with the Qt IDE.  I want to make an app to integrate with the Flickr API.  I've got to the point where i need to make a call to a URL.

**Flickr API**:

> http://flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.people.getInfo&api_key=987654321&auth_token=9765984&api_sig=8f3870be274f6c49b3e31a0c6728957f

Right then .....  I'm used to .NET so this would normally be easy. Is there something built into Qt to allow me to do this or do i need a C++ web API. If I do need an API can you recommend one that would do the job.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [QNetworkAccessManager](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qnetworkaccessmanager.html). The page has an example.

Answer (score 1):

we do use Qt but ended up using the cURLpp C++ wrapper for libCURL (http://curlpp.org/) for a similar project.